# Can WiX ignore failure of a service to start?

Tags: service, installation, wix, windows-installer, wix3.10

Using WiX 3.10.3

I have a service which has failed to start during the installation process. It is desired that this failure to start NOT cause the installation to fail and roll back.

My service config:

```
<ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstall" Name="MyService" DisplayName="My Service"
                Description="My Service Description" ErrorControl="ignore" Vital="yes"
                Account="LOCALSYSTEM" Type="ownProcess" Start="auto" Interactive="no" />
<ServiceConfig ServiceName="MyService" DelayedAutoStart="yes" OnInstall="yes" OnReinstall ="yes"  />
<ServiceControl Id="ServiceControl" Name="MyService" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Wait="yes" />
```

I have not come across the right combination of attributes which would permit the installer to attempt to start the service but ignore the result.  Is this possible?

Comment: Set `Wait="no"` in your ServiceControl and also set `Vital="no"` in your ServiceInstall.

Comment: Thanks, Brian, I will give that a try.